# How to perform sum of vector elements if it contains another vector?

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have the similar code in **[R](http://www.r-project.org/)** which gives warnings:

```
> require(pracma) # for integral
> v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) #some vector of unknown length
> v2 <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 0) #another vector of the same length as v1
# Here I want to sum by v1 & v2 elements, but the sum contains x argument
> f <- function(x) x^(-2i) sum(v1 / (1 - v2 * x)^2)
> integral(f, 1e-12, 1)

49: In v2 * x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
50: In v1/(1 - v2 * x)^2 : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I use [R-studio](https://www.rstudio.com/) for debugging purpose, and I see that **[integral](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/)** function pass a vector to the **f** function.

I understand that **v2** is a vector and **x** is a vector. But I'm currently don't know how to make this work without warnings. I have tried to put **[Vectorize(x)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html)** in the **[sum](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html)** function, but warnings are still here.

How to properly handle this situation?

Comment: Use Vectorize on f - not on sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two problems here. The first is the need to vectorize the function. The second is that your function returns a complex value (although the argument is real). You can integrate complex functions using the `myintegrate(...)` function in the `elliptic` package.

```
library(elliptic)
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
v2 <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 0)

f <- function(x) x^(-2i) * sum(v1 / (1 - v2 * x)^2)
g <- Vectorize(f)
myintegrate(g, 1e-12, 1)
# [1] -3173.272-8530.861i
```

Comment: As you said, I can use **myintegrate(...)** function. Do you think the results of **myintegrate** and **integral** functions for real argument of complex functions will differ noticeably (no R under the hand)?